# Login to space-track.org with java

Tags: java, android

I want to login to my spacetrack account in order to download by code some orbital data.
Following the instruction found on the site for java users I test this portion of code:

```
private static void loginSpaceTrack() {

    try {
        String baseURL = "https://www.space­track.org";
        String authPath = "/auth/login";
        String userName = "USERNAME";
        String password = "PASSWORD";
        String query = "/basicspacedata/query/class/tle_latest/ORDINAL/1/EPOCH/%3Enow­30/orderby/NORAD_CAT_ID/format/3le";

        CookieManager manager = new CookieManager();
        manager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
        CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);

        URL url = new URL(baseURL + authPath);

        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        String input = "identity=" + userName + "&password=" + password;
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(input.getBytes());
        os.flush();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {

        }
        url = new URL(baseURL + query);
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((url.openStream())));

        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {

        }
        url = new URL(baseURL + "/ajaxauth/logout"); 
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((url.openStream())));
        conn.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

obviously changing USERNAME and PASSWORD with my Account.

At the point: `OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();`
I have an exception: UnknownHostException

Note that at this point I haven't login with my credentials.

Similar issue in android

Someone could help me to fix this problem ?
Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change ur baseURL:

```
String baseURL = "https://www.space-track.org";
```